# why do we need subscriber method :Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am having hard time understanding Angular2 Http(Observable) methods:

Here is my code:

```
login(username:string,password:string) {
    let headers = new Headers();

    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers,username,password);

    return this.http
        .get(this.url,{headers:headers})
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body.data || { };
}
```

My Question is : **Why do we need subscribe method**, if we can extract the data and everything else in a map method of an Observable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP calls are asynchronous, that means that they don't finish immediately after being called.

The `subscribe` method, does two things:

1. it 'starts' the call (in this case it sends the HTTP request)
2. it calls the function that you pass as a parameter (callback function) after the call has completed, with the data that has been returned.

Answer (score 1):

Without `subscribe()` nothing will happen. `Observable`s are lazy and only when `subscribe()`, `toPromise()`, or `forEach()` is called they are executed.

You don't need to do anything in `subscribe()`, it just needs to be called.

```
return this.http.get(this.url,{headers:headers})
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

or

```
return this.http.get(this.url,{headers:headers})
    .subscribe(this.extractData, this.handleError);
```